# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - POST method not being hit when GET action method receives parameter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

Why is this not working?

In create `GET`, I am receiving an optional `idEnt` parameter.

If I call in browser `MyController/Create/5`, it shows view ok, and even client validation works ok, but on form submit, the `POST` action method in controller is not being hit... why?

(it does not throw any exception either, it just reloads the view)

Controller:

```
[Route("MyController/Create/{idEnt:int?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int? idEnt) 
{
    MyEntity ent = db.Find(idEnt);

    var mod = new Mod() { idEnt = idEnt }

    return View(mod);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[WebTrail(AuditLevel = 3)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Mod mod) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        _db.Add(mod);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(mod);
}
```

View:

```
@model My.Namespace.Mod
    <div>
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IdEnt" />

            <label asp-for="someField" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="someField" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="someField" class="text-danger"></span>

            //more form inputs etc here

            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Model:

```
public class Mod 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ent")]
    public int? IdEnt { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0}€", NullDisplayText = "---")]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(15,2)")]
    public decimal? SomeField { get; set; }

    public virtual Ent Ent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider adding [Route("MyController/Create/{idEnt:int?}")] to POST method too?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It seems that's the correct way to do it in .NET CORE MVC? in .NET MVC I could have a GET method receive a parameter, but that did not mean the POST method have to receive it too... a bit weird if you ask me...